# edit_message can not be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I am getting this error. It says "edit_message can not be ressolved or is not a field" Can somebody tell me why I am getting this error is how can I fix it.

LAYOUT OF MAIN ACTIVITY: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CODE OF MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.practice.firstapp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE= "com.practice.fristapp1.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); ///********ERRORR***********
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

LAYOUT OF SECOND ACTIVITY: -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE OF SECOND ACTIVITY: -

```
package com.practice.firstapp1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

STRING RESOURCES:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is right. Check the following things:

1) Save the layouts in xml, one reason could be its not saved.
2) Check there is no error in your xmls and project is build.
3) If you are using eclipse, go to Projects->Clean All Projects and then projects->Build Automatically.
4) Open your activity and press **"cmd + shift + o"** or **ctrl+ shift+o** (in windows). It shall import the R.java, select the com..R in the options.

I hope it shall solve the error.

Comment: OK. Thank you. The step 3 worked, now can you please tell me what "clean all projects" did?

Comment: Secondly can you also tell me what you meant by checking if my project is built? Does building mean compiling?

Comment: Yes you can consider it as compiling. You might want to select projects->Build Automatically. That will automatically build the project in background, whenever you will make some changes.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `import com.practice.firstapp1.R` in `MainActivity.java`.

See [the docs on Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I had not seen the previous answer before and I added the import statement which did not help the bug but I did learn something, so thank you very much.